# If .jpg Or .gif Then Show The Link

Tags: php, extract

I have something like:

```
{if !(strstr(substr($firstsub.url_add,-4), '.jpg'))}
<b><a href="{$firstsub.url_add}" target="_blank">{$firstsub.url_add}</a></b>
{/if}
```

But how to add also .gif, .jpeg others... I mean if .jpg OR .gif OR .jpeg then show the link.
Of course if $firstsub.url_add contains .jpg, OR .gif extension, I wanna to show the link.

If I use this:

```
{if !(strstr(substr($firstsub.url_add,-4), '.jpg')) || !(strstr(substr($firstsub.url_add,-4), '.gif'))}
<b><a href="{$firstsub.url_add}" target="_blank">{$firstsub.url_add}</a></b>
{/if}
```

system understand this like AND.
Please help :)

Comment: Don't ALLCAPS, it's considered shouting/rude

Comment: Answer is pretty simple: fix your logic so the "system understands" what you want from it. Programming is all about implementing a proper logic, unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [`pathinfo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) and [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to get this done elegantly like below:

```
{if in_array(pathinfo($firstsub.url_add, PATHINFO_EXTENSION),["jpg","jpeg","gif"])}
    <b><a href="{$firstsub.url_add}" target="_blank">{$firstsub.url_add}</a></b>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{if in_array(pathinfo($firstsub.url_add, PATHINFO_EXTENSION),["jpg","jpeg","gif","png"]) == false}
    <b><a href="{$firstsub.url_add}" target="_blank">{$firstsub.url_add}</a></b>
{/if}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you wrote it the other way round.  You can just add `png` too in my answer to make it work.